# pipe command's output to dialog and allow to scroll up

Tags: bash

I want to run an arbitrary command, for example 
`find / -name "a*"`
I want to pipe its output to to dialog.  --tailbox and --progressbox handle this well, except that if the output becomes too much, you can only see as much as the screen fits.

I need to be able to use up/down arrows and/or pg up/pg dn keys to scroll up and see the previous output. There are other options that allow scroll bars, but none of them seem to allow piping output to them.

Edit: 
I have found an example that purports to do this, but I honestly don't understand how it works or how to translate it to the example of `find / -name "a*"`. 
    see the last example on http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/040

Edit 2: The only requirement is the use dialog (or something like it allowing ncurses like gui for command line, and native gui boxes if X is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `--tailbox` and `--progressbox` handle this well, except that if the output becomes too much, you can only see as much as the screen fits.

That is not entirely correct. A `--tailbox` allows you to scroll left and right. But it does not allow you to scroll up and down, which is a pity.

To work around this, you can provide the `--tailbox` with an `--extra-button` that triggers, e.g., a `--textbox`. (Then the “Exit” button becomes an “OK” button, so you have to use `--ok-label` if you want to change its caption.)

Closing the `--textbox` can either abort or return to the `--tailbox`.  In the following, it returns to the `--tailbox`:

```
(
  log=/tmp/make-kernel.log

  # start process that writes to "$log" here

  exit_status=1

  while [ $exit_status -ne 0 ]
  do
    dialog \
      --ok-label Close \
      --extra-button --extra-label Inspect \
      --tailbox "$log" 21 80

    exit_status=$?

    if [ $exit_status -eq 255 ]; then
      dialog --textbox "$log" 21 80
    fi
  done
)
```

> Edit: I have found an example that purports to do this, but I honestly don't understand how it works or how to translate it to the example of `find / -name "a*"`. see the last example on http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/040

Thank you very much for referring to that example.  Finally I understand how `--tailboxbg` is supposed to work.

However, by contrast to my approach, this example “as is” would *not* allow you to scroll the output (nor does it purport to do this).  Also, here (dialog 1.3-20160828), no button is displayed in the `--tailbox`, which by comparison is not user-friendly.

The way it "works" is as follows:

```
# POSIX
# you cannot tail a nonexistent file, so always ensure it pre-exists!
> dialog-tail.log
```

“Create an empty file `dialog-tail.log` so that the `dialog` below can display the file even if nothing has been written into it yet.”

```
{
    for i in 1 2 3; do 
        printf '%d\n' "$i"
        sleep 1
    done

    printf 'Done\n'
} > dialog-tail.log &
```

“Write the numbers from 1 to 3 into the file `dialog-tail.log`, each on its own line (`\n`), one number per second (`sleep 1`), and do that in the background (`&`).”

**In your case, you would replace `{ … }` with `find / -name 'a*'`.** You might also want to redirect `find`’s standard error stream.

```
dialog --title "TAIL BOXES" \
       --begin 10 10 --tailboxbg dialog-tail.log 8 58 \
       --and-widget \
       --begin 3 10 --msgbox "Press OK " 5 30
```

“Display the file in a box at line 10, column 10, with title ‘TAIL BOXES’ as if by `tail`(1), but run that box in the background (`--tailboxbg` instead of `--tailbox`), so that an additional widget (`--and-widget`) can be immediately displayed starting at line 3, column 10 (`--begin 3 10`; above the tail box). That widget is a `--msgbox` with text ‘Press OK ’, height 5, and width 30.”

```
wait
```

“Do not execute the following commands until all child processes in the background have exited (here: the process that writes to the file, and `dialog`).” (RTFM, respectively)

Answer (score 1):

Simply pipe your command into `more` and you'll be able to use standard BASH movement keys (or up/down) to move around the output.  In your case...

```
find / -name "a*" | more
```

...should do the trick.

Comment: that does work, but this is part of a much larger program that uses dialog; so dialog is really the only requirement here.  I have successfully tried this using zenity, but I don't want to port all of my code, and zenity can't run in ncurses mode without X.

Comment: Ahh gotcha, sorry for the misunderstanding.  I thought you were just looking for a way to scroll through output.

Comment: To add to that, `less` does the same thing, but the output is better imho.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a temporary file for this:

```
file=$(mktemp)
cat > "$file"
dialog --textbox "$file" 0 0
rm "$file"
```

Comment: Easy engough, but what if the progress is long? Could I see the dialog box, while it is in progress? (like when you search in mc)?

Comment: @pihentagy Yes, see my answer.